# Add type hint for os.DirEntry

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I'm struggling with adding type hints to a function that accepts an `os.DirEntry` object (these are produced by `os.scandir()`). Here's a simple visitor class that accepts `DirEntry` objects:

```
class FileSystemVisitor:
    def visit_dir(self, entry) -> None:
        ...
    def visit_file(self, entry) -> None:
        ...
```

An instance of `FileSystemVisitor` is being fed to a `visit()` function that traverses the given directory's subtree:

```
def traverse(path: Union[str, pathlib.Path], visitor: FileSystemVisitor) -> None:
    for entry in os.scandir(str(path)):
        if entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False):
            visitor.visit_dir(entry)
            traverse(entry.path, visitor)
        else:
            visitor.visit_file(entry)
```

How to add type hint for the `entry` argument in the `FileSystemVisitor.visit_{dir(),file()}` functions? I can't import `DirEntry` for that matter.

```
$ python3.5 -c "from os import DirEntry"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'DirEntry'
```

---

One thing I can think of is writing a dummy class that mimics `DirEntry` and use it for type hinting:

```
class DirEntryType:
    name = None  # type: str
    path = None  # type: str

    def inode(self) -> int:
        ...
    def is_dir(self) -> bool:
        ...
    def is_file(self) -> bool:
        ...
    def is_symlink(self) -> bool:
        ...
    def stat(self) -> os.stat_result:
        ...
```

However, is adding a whole class for just type hinting that clever?

If this matters, I'm stuck with `python3.5` so the features of `python3.6` are not available.

---

#### Edit

As pointed out by [avigil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7088038/avigil) in the comments, `DirEntry` can be imported in `python3.6`:

```
$ python3.6 -c "from os import DirEntry; print(DirEntry)"
<class 'posix.DirEntry'>
```

The backward-compatible solution could thus be for example:

```
# typing_utils.py

class DirEntryStub:
    name = None  # type: str
    path = None  # type: str

    def inode(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError('This class is used for type hints only')
    def is_dir(self, follow_symlinks: bool = False) -> bool:
        raise NotImplementedError('This class is used for type hints only')
    def is_file(self, follow_symlinks: bool = False) -> bool:
        raise NotImplementedError('This class is used for type hints only')
    def is_symlink(self) -> bool:
        raise NotImplementedError('This class is used for type hints only')
    def stat(self) -> os.stat_result:
        raise NotImplementedError('This class is used for type hints only')
```

Now I can type the `FileSystemVisitor`:

```
try:
    from os import DirEntry
except ImportError:
    from typing_utils import DirEntryStub as DirEntry

class FileSystemVisitor:
    def visit_dir(self, entry: DirEntry) -> None:
        ...
    def visit_file(self, entry: DirEntry) -> None:
        ...
```

Comment: unfortunate, as this was a [bug fixed in 3.6](https://bugs.python.org/issue27038)

Comment: @avigil dang, indeed I can import `DirEntry` in `python3.6`. Thanks for the hint! If you wish to make an answer out of the comment, I will accept it. The solution as I see it would then be a python version check and the import or the use of the custom class: `if sys.version_info >= (3, 6): from os import DirEntry; else: from my_os import DirEntryType as DirEntry`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DirEntry` is implemented in C in the posix module, but unfortunately was left unexposed in python until the 3.6 release. See [bpo-27038](https://bugs.python.org/issue27038) for the relevant python bug tracker issue.

For earlier versions you can do as you suggested and stub it out, unless you care enough to go through the effort of compiling your own [patched version](https://bugs.python.org/file43130/issue27038.patch). This actually wouldn't be *too* hard since the `scandir` implementation comes originally from the [scandir](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir) package which could be patched and brought in as a dependency in favor of the standard library implementation.

Comment: The `scandir` package actually has an open issue for this: https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir/issues/70